# Ruby each vs while loop performance

Tags: ruby, performance, while-loop, each

trying to resolve a basic problem of algorithm in Ruby, and testing performance.

Just in case, the algorithm aims to find the smallest positive number that is evenly divisible by all of the numbers from 1 to 20.
Here's the code :

```
def remainder(number) # with while
  divisor = 2
  while divisor < 21
    return false unless number % divisor == 0
    divisor += 1
  end
  true
end

def remainder(number) # with each
  (2..20).each do |divisor|
    return false unless number % divisor == 0
  end
  true
end

number = 180_000_000
while number < 10_000_000_000
  if remainder number
    puts "#{number}"
    break
  end
  number += 1
end
```

On my computer, with while version, Ruby takes around 10 seconds, with each version, it takes between 70 and 80 seconds to resolve. Code does the exact same thing, gives same result. Why such a difference in performance ?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

It seems the cost is added by:

1. Creation of enumerator for range object (2..20)
2. Invocation of block in the `each`

Here is a benchmark

```
require 'benchmark'

c = 100_000
Benchmark.bm(7) do |x|
  x.report("range - 1 :") { c.times { (2..20) } }
  x.report("range - 2 :") { c.times { (2..20).each } }
  x.report("range - 3 :") { c.times { (2..20).each { |x| x } } }
end
```

Sample output of above is:

```
              user     system      total        real
range - 1 :  0.000000   0.000000   0.000000 (  0.006004)
range - 2 :  0.031000   0.000000   0.031000 (  0.026017)
range - 3 :  0.125000   0.000000   0.125000 (  0.122081)
[Finished in 0.4s]
```

As can be seen, creation of Range object is not a problem, but creating an enumerator for it adds time, and passing a block to that iterator and executing some code, adds further cost.

Compared to this, the `while` loop implementation is doing primitive operations. Hence, is faster.

Please note that `for` loop will perform as badly as `each`, as it is more or less equivalent to `each` implementation

Comment: Also worth noting, you are comparing these small-ish costs relative to cost of `return false unless number % divisor == 0` which is not much Ruby code at all. It would be wrong to take away the message that in Ruby you should avoid instantiating enumerators on Ranges or using block-based methods to structure your code. It is only in rare situations that you would see a large time difference

Answer (score 3):

`each` is a method, and it's implemented <s>using `while`</s> in C using a `for` loop, which (in C) does the same thing you `while` loop does. Internally it needs to hold a counter, initialize it to `2` and increment it up to `20` - the same thing your `while` version needs to do. But the `each` version also has the overhead of creating a function(the block), sending it to the `each` method, and calling it on every iteration of the `for` loop inside the `each` method's implementation. All this requires extra work from the computer which makes the code slower.

Comment: And the `each` version creates and garbage collects a `(2..20)` range `number` times...

Comment: #each on a range is implemented with a `for` loop - http://ruby-doc.org/core-2.2.3/Range.html#method-i-each

Comment: @NeilSlater - I thought the same thing but isn't `while something; end` and `while something do; end` equivalent?

Comment: @Anthony: Not all appearances of `do` in Ruby code create blocks. The `do` version of `while` does not create a block AFAIK, it is just a syntax variation.

Comment: @NeilSlater: Yep. The `do` is simply used to separate the condition from the loop body, just like `then` is used in `if` and `case`. You can replace it with a line break or a semicolon, again, just like in `if` and `case`.

Comment: @Anthony: Yes, you are correct - a range's `each` is implemented using a `for` loop. I'll fix it. However, it's implemented in C using C's `for` loop - which is syntactic sugar over a while loop - and not using Ruby's `for` loop, which is actually implemented using the `each` method.